# How do I access a twoport's edge coordinates?

Tags: circuitikz

Example: I have a circuit looking like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[adc,>] ++(2,0) to[twoport,t={DSP},>] ++(2, 0) to[dac,>] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and I want to position an arrow (different style) to the DSP's south.

I know that the DSP must have a name to be accessible. When I try to create it from a node

```
\draw (0,2) node[twoport] (tp1) {Two port};
```

there is no box dawn around it.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to create the twoport box myself? If yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`twoport` isn'a a node style, it more or less just sets the `to path`, so using it for a node doesn't make sense.

But in your first example you can just do `to[twoport,t={DSP},>,name=foo]`, and then draw an arrow to `foo.south`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[adc,>] ++(2,0) to[twoport,t={DSP},>,name=foo] ++(2, 0) to[dac,>] ++(2,0);
    \draw [stealth-] (foo.south) -- ++(0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly well. Thank you very much!